# Laravel 5.5 Inconsistent JSON when using filter on a collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am building a simple search for a project I am working on. It works fairly well for the most part. I am running into an issue when using `->filter(function($item) { .. })`.

Here is the code:

```
$users = App\User::select(['id', 'username', 'preferred_first_name', 'preferred_last_name'])
        ->where('username', 'like', $like)
        ->orWhere('preferred_first_name', 'like', $like)
        ->orWhere('preferred_last_name', 'like', $like)
        ->orWhere('id', $query)
        ->get();
$users = $users->filter(function($item) {
    return !$item->is_terminated();
});
return UserResource::collection($users);
```

And here is the `toArray` function in `UserResource`:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'username' => $this->username,
        'full_name' => $this->full_name,
    ];
}
```

The issue I am having is some of the JSON is returned in two different formats:

Format A: `{ data: [ {..}, {..}, .. ] }`
Format B: `{ data: {"0": {..}, "1":{..},..} }`

I would like all the JSON to be returned in Format A all the time. I've narrowed it down the `filter()` function. But it is inconsistent. On the search term `san` it returns in Format B but on the term `pha` it returns in Format A. If removed everything works perfectly and is returned in the proper format (Format A).

If there's any code missing that could help let me know as I am unsure what needs to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter()` function preserves the order of the collection in which it was initially retrieved. In my case the collection array, after filtering, would be:
`[3 => {}, 25 => {},..]`. I am unaware of the reason/logic Laravel uses to output this array as an object of objects (`{data: { "3": {..}, "25": {..},..} }`) but it does. I can't seem to find anything in the docs. If anyone has a specific answer for this that would be great. I assume it has to do with skipping of keys - going from 3 to 25.

Using the `values()` function re-orders the collection and properly returns the JSON as `{ data: [{..},{..}] }`.